# using awk match 1 column to another in two files and then do date subtraction for the matching records

Tags: date, unix, awk

Using `awk` match  1 column to another in two files and then do date subtraction(in days) for the matching records.

Lets suppose i have two files

file1:

```
123,2-jul-2016
124,2-jul-2018
```

file2:

```
123,2-jul-2015
124,2-jul-2017
```

If matched then give me output as

```
123,366
124,366
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are you tried?

Comment: @A.r. Naresh, always try to add your efforts in your posts as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[,-]"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    mthNr = (index("janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec",$3)+2)/3
    date  = sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00", $4, mthNr, $2)
    secs  = mktime(date)
}
NR==FNR {
    end[$1] = secs
    next
}
{
    print $1, int((end[$1] - secs) / (24*60*60))
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
123,366
124,365
```

The expected output in your question was wrong as it didn't account for the leap day in feb 2016 or for 2015 it's assuming that, for example, the difference between 3 and 4 is 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,oct,nov,dec",month,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    daymonth[month[i]]=i}
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in a){
  split($2,array2,"-")
  split(a[$1],array1,"-")
  print $1,(mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0 0",array2[3],daymonth[array2[2]],array2[1]))-\
            mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0 0",array1[3],daymonth[array1[2]],array1[1])))\
                  /86400
}'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Comment: @A.r.Naresh, sure, try to up-vote all answers which would have helped you.